Error loading the extension in autodesk forge viewer
I am using this extension and downloading it successfully
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/add-mapbox-google-maps-forge-viewer
https://github.com/wallabyway/geo-three-ext
But when executing the extension script itself, it gives an error

I tried to fix the error in this way
var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('MyViewerDiv');
Like in my web application, but he switched to .addScen, and swore at him

I updated the demo:  https://wallabyway.github.io/geo-three-ext/
You can see how the viewer is initialized in the source code, here:
https://github.com/wallabyway/geo-three-ext/blob/657c6803428d66fe837c2c6725ebca5c4cb86381/docs/index.html#L33
That viewer variable is the problem and should be refactored.  Add that to your code, and it should unblocked you for now.
