Error loading the extension in autodesk forge viewer with react
I am trying to use Autodesk Forge with this extension
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/add-mapbox-google-maps-forge-viewer in my React application.
enter image description here
In my app I use this Forge viewer wrapping https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/viewer-react-sample/blob/master/src/components/Viewer.jsx
ForgeViewer:
/// import * as Autodesk from "@types/forge-viewer";

import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const { Autodesk } = window;

const runtime = {
    /** @type {Autodesk.Viewing.InitializerOptions} */
    options: null,
    /** @type {Promise<void>} */
    ready: null
};

/**
 * Initializes global runtime for communicating with Autodesk Platform Services.
 * Calling this function repeatedly with different options is not allowed, and will result in an exception.
 * @async
 * @param {Autodesk.Viewing.InitializerOptions} options Runtime initialization options.
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
function initializeViewerRuntime(options) {
    if (!runtime.ready) {
        runtime.options = { ...options };
        runtime.ready = new Promise((resolve) => Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(runtime.options, resolve));
    } else {
        if (['accessToken', 'getAccessToken', 'env', 'api', 'language'].some(prop => options[prop] !== runtime.options[prop])) {
            return Promise.reject('Cannot initialize another viewer runtime with different settings.')
        }
    }
    console.log(runtime.ready)
    return runtime.ready;
}

/**
 * Wrapper for the Autodesk Platform Services viewer component.
 */
class ForgeViewer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        /** @type {HTMLDivElement} */
        this.container = null;
        /** @type {Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D} */
        this.viewer = null;

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        initializeViewerRuntime(this.props.runtime)
            .then(_ => {
                console.log(this.container)

                this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(this.container,
                    { extensions: ["GeoThreeExtension","DrawToolExtension","TransformationExtension", "LoggerExtension","SummaryExtension"] });
                this.viewer.start();
                // this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, this.onViewerCameraChange);
                // this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, this.onViewerSelectionChange);
                this.updateViewerState({});
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.viewer) {
            this.viewer.removeEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, this.onViewerCameraChange);
            this.viewer.removeEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, this.onViewerSelectionChange);
            this.viewer.finish();
            this.viewer = null;
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.viewer) {
            this.updateViewerState(prevProps);
        }
    }

    updateViewerState(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.urn && this.props.urn !== prevProps.urn) {
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
                'urn:' + this.props.urn,
                (doc) => this.viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry()),
                (code, message, errors) => console.error(code, message, errors)
            );
        } else if (!this.props.urn && this.viewer.model) {
            this.viewer.unloadModel(this.viewer.model);
        }

        const selectedIds = this.viewer.getSelection();
        if (JSON.stringify(this.props.selectedIds || []) !== JSON.stringify(selectedIds)) {
            this.viewer.select(this.props.selectedIds);
        }
    }

    onViewerCameraChange = () => {
        if (this.props.onCameraChange) {
            this.props.onCameraChange({ viewer: this.viewer, camera: this.viewer.getCamera() });
        }
    }

    onViewerSelectionChange = () => {
        if (this.props.onSelectionChange) {
            this.props.onSelectionChange({ viewer: this.viewer, ids: this.viewer.getSelection() });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div ref={ref => this.container = ref}></div>
            </>
        );
    }
}

ForgeViewer.propTypes = {
    /** Viewer runtime initialization options. */
    runtime: PropTypes.object,
    /** URN of model to be loaded. */
    urn: PropTypes.string,
    /** List of selected object IDs. */
    selectedIds: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),
    /** Callback for when the viewer camera changes. */
    onCameraChange: PropTypes.func,
    /** Callback for when the viewer selectio changes. */
    onSelectionChange: PropTypes.func
};

export default ForgeViewer;

Usage of component ForgeViewer
<ForgeViewer
     runtime={{ accessToken: this.state.accesstoken }}
     urn={'dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Y29uc29saWRhdGVkL3JtZV9hZHZhbmNlZF9zYW1wbGVfcHJvamVjdC5ydnQ'}                  
     ref={ref => this.wrapper = ref}
/>

When I try to initialize viewer, it gives me this error:
Uncaught
ReferenceError: viewer is not defined
at GeoThreeExtension.load (geo-three.ext.js:12:3)
at e.‹computed> [as load] (ExtensionEventsMixin.js:26:33)
at P.loadExtensionLocal (ExtensionManager.js:390:38)
at P.loadExtension (ExtensionManager.js:249:25)
at $.setUp (Viewer3D.js:815:22)
at P.setUp (GuiViewer3D.js:177:34)
at Viewer3D.js:392:39

How can I fix this problem?
I tried to set this.viewer = null, but it didn't work.

Can you show us some of your code as text?

same problem resolved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78394334/error-loading-the-extension-in-autodesk-forge-viewer
but i can't understand how to do this in react

The extension class expects a global viewer variable - so you can either create that or modify the extension's code to use this.viewer instead like here: https://github.com/adamenagy/geo-three-ext/blob/main/docs/geo-three.ext.js
